# Remove excess whitespace at bottom of ListView item

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been having some troubles with excess whitespace at the bottom of ListView items. Example with white/negative space marked with red arrows at https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpm7a.png

Here's my layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.thereversecookbook.ResultsList" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/results_list_lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my list item XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!-- cooking time -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0033"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_clock" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textColor="#3399FF"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:longClickable="false" 
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And CustomListAdapter:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtCookingTime;
        RatingBar ratingBar;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtCookingTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.ratingBar = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else 
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtCookingTime.setText(rowItem.getCookingTime());
        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
        //holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
        holder.ratingBar.setRating(rowItem.getRating());
        holder.ratingBar.setStepSize((float)0.5);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this? Many thanks!

Comment: Are you inflating this layout yourself in your `ListAdapter`? If yes, please post your code for it.

Comment: There ya go @CommonsWare !

Comment: @JustinFlowers What are the dimensions of your `ic_clock` drawable?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri
I made ic_clock using http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html so I believe I have the correct sized copies in each drawable folder in res.

Comment: @ShobitPuri and the one being shown is 60 x 60 px

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
```

Bzzzt. Don't use that `inflate()` method. You want to use the three-parameter version, passing in your `convertView` ("the inflated widgets will eventually be a child of this...") and `false` ("...but don't make them be children of it right away"):

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
```

That's particularly important in your case, as `RelativeLayout` gets weird if it's the root container of your layout file and you *don't* use this version of the `inflate()` method.

You can read more about this in [Dave Smith's "Layout Inflation as Intended" blog post](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Added your change, and modifications to `android:layout_etc` finally started working in my list_item.xml. I'll remember this next time I'm getting whitespace issues with ListViews. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, for clarity's sake I used `convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);` but I assumed that's what you meant from the blog post

Comment: @JustinFlowers: Yes, sorry, made a mistake there. I have edited the answer to match.